# creating category if it doesn't exist, print current data if it does

Tags: bash, awk

I have some text files with lines of categories and a numerical datum for each category. Although there are a limited number of categories, say *a* through *g*, not all files have every category, e.g.:

file1:

```
a 199
b 20
c 70
e 1
f 200
```

file2:

```
a 11
b 103
c 232
d 92
f 7
g 201
```

file3:

```
a 100
b 120
c 9
d 20
e 33
f 123
g 9191
```

I would like to produce output files such that if the category already exists, the line is reproduced, but if the category doesn't exist, the category is created with a numerical datum of 0. I thought of using

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /category/ {print $0}'
```

for the categories that already exist, but I'm unsure how to introduce the new ones.

Any solution, even if it's not with `awk`, would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a hint: `awk '$1 ~ /category/ {print $0}'` can be simplified to `awk '$1 ~ /category/'` ... `{print}`, which is the same as `{print $0}` is the default action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you also have a file with the categories in them:

```
$ cat categories
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

Let's also assume that all categories are simple words without spaces, and that all your files are sorted on the category column. **EDIT**: Actually, any category string goes, but you'd be better off to use a delimiter like tab or comma or something in your files, in which case add `-t ","` to the `join` command below (if you use commas that is). *See end of answer for an example*.

Then this solves your problem:

```
$ join -a 1 -o 1.1,2.2 -e 0 categories file1
a 199
b 20
c 70
d 0
e 1
f 200
g 0
```

The `join` utility performs a relational join operation on the first column (by default) of two files.  Here, we're feeding it with the `categories` file and the first example file.

The `-a 1` option says "give me *all* lines from the first input file (`categories`), even if they do not match lines in the second file (`file1`)".

The `-o 1.1,2.2` option says "I'd like to see column 1 from the first file, and column 2 from the second file in the output".

The `-e 0` option says "replace any missing values with `0`".

**EDIT**: Remember that both input files to `join` *have to be sorted* on the field that we use to perform the join on (the first field of all files in this case, so a simple `sort -o file file` on each file will do). If the files were not sorted, then `join` would need to read them into memory, and like many other Unix tools, this is not the way it was implemented. Instead, it's a memory efficient and fast tool that place only slightly stricter requirements on its input data. Those restrictions are easily handled by other tools (`sort`). This is the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) in action.

**EDIT**: Example with multi-word categories:

```
$ cat categories
a category
b nice
c at
d cide
e ffective
f ull of gas
g one

$ cat file1
a category,199
b nice,20
c at,70
e ffective,1
f ull of gas,200

$ join -t "," -a 1 -o 1.1,2.2 -e 0 categories file1
a category,199
b nice,20
c at,70
d cide,0
e ffective,1
f ull of gas,200
g one,0
```

Comment: thanks, this works great as well, with the pre-requisite that the files are sorted by category beforehand.

Comment: @Amir Yes, the files have to be sorted on the field that we use with `join` (the first field of all files in this case), so a simple `sort -o file file` on each file will do. If the files were not sorted, then `join` would need to read them into memory, and like many other Unix tools, this i ot the way it was implemented. Instead, it's a memory efficient and fast tool that place only slightly stricter requirements on its input data :-)

Comment: if they're not in order, use `--nocheck-order` but thanks for the explanation about memory usage!

Comment: @Amir No, if they are not in order you *must* sort them, otherwise you'll get the wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

Using `file1` as an example:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=$2} END{split("abcdefg",b,//); for (i in b) print b[i],a[b[i]]+0}' file1
a 199
b 20
c 70
d 0
e 1
f 200
g 0
```

#### How it works

- `a[$1]=$2`

  For each line read, we save the value in column in associative array `a` with the category (column 1) as the key.
- `END{split("abcdefg",b,//); for (i in b) print b[i],a[b[i]]+0}`

  After we have finished reading the file, we create an array `b` which has, as values, all the categories.  Thus `b[1]` is `a` and `b[3]` is `c`, etc.

  Next, for each element in `b`, we print out the value saved in array `a`.  If no value was saved in `a`, then awk gives us the default value.  To make sure that the default value is zero, as opposed to an empty string, we add `0` to the value in `a` which forces awk to treat the value in `a` as a number.

#### Handling multi-letter categories

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file2
category1 1
category2 2
```

Now, let's analyze it according to three categories:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=$2} END{split("category1_category2_category3",b,"_"); for (i in b) print b[i],a[b[i]]+0}' file2
category1 1
category2 2
category3 0
```

Comment: Is it possible to define the categories other than letters? I attempted to do, for example:

`$ awk '{a[$1]=$2} END{split("category1_category2_category3",b,"_"); for (i in b) print b[i],a[b[i]]+0}' file1`

but the output returns 0 for all the categories

`category1 0
category2 0
category3 0`

Comment: @Amir That works for me.  See the example that I just added to the end of the answer: it shows your code being used successfully.

Comment: worked great, just curious how the first argument works for `a[$1]=$2`, if my categories were in another column, say column 2, changing it to `a[$2]=$2` doesn't work, but `a[$2]=$1` does.

Comment: Very good.  In `a[$1]=$2`, the first `$` argument is the column that has the key and the second is `$` is for the column that has the value.  So, as you found, if the value was in the first column and the category in the second, then use `a[$2]=$1`.  Alternatively, if the category was in the third column and the value in the fifth, then it would be `a[$3]=$5`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the order:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    split("a b c d e f g",p);
    i=1
}
p[i]!=$1{
    print p[i],0;
    i++
}
{
    i++;
    print
}
END{
    for (j=i;j<=7;j++)print p[j],0
}' file
```